# What exactly is Levy hierarchy?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Wikipedia lacks information on Levy hierarchy, so what exactly is Levy hierarchy? This will tell me what $\Delta_0$ means in KP set theory.

Comment: What does KP abbreviate?

Comment: @Berci Kripke-Platek set theory

Answer (score 9):

A formula in the language of set theory is called $\Delta_0$ (or $\Sigma_0$ or $\Pi_0$) if all of the quantifiers appearing in it are bounded, that is if they are all of the form $\forall x\in y$ or $\exists x\in y$. Note that all $\Delta_0$ formulae have free variables as to have something to bound the quantifiers with (Matthews-Rathjen, "[Constructing the Constructible Universe Constructively](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.08283v1)" (2022, p.11)). A formula is called $\Sigma_{n+1}$ if it is of the form
$\exists x_1\dots\exists x_k\colon\varphi$, where $\varphi$ is $\Pi_n$. A formula is called $\Pi_{n+1}$ if it is of the form $\forall x_1\dots\forall x_k\colon \varphi$, where $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_n$.

This classification is quite rigid: the formulas appearing have a very specific form, with all of the unbounded quantifiers outside. If you are given some theory $T$, you can do a similar and slightly more useful classification based on $T$-provable equivalence. That is to say, a formula is called $\Sigma_n^T$ if it is $T$-provably equivalent to a $\Sigma_n$ formula (and similarly for $\Pi_n^T$). A formula is called $\Delta_n^T$ if it is both $\Sigma_n^T$ and $\Pi_n^T$ (note that there is no such thing as a $\Delta_n$ formula).

Both of these hierarchies are called the Lévy hierarchy.

It is also quite common (as Asaf points out in the comments) to replace the $\Sigma_n$ and $\Pi_n$ of the basic hierarchy with $\Sigma_n^\emptyset$ and $\Pi_n^\emptyset$, in effect modding out by logical equivalence.

Comment: It is often better to require logical equivalence (over the empty theory) when defining the hierarchy. This way the classes are closed under conjunction and disjunction.

Comment: "note that there is no such thing as a $\Delta_n$ formula." I've been confused about this, why can't we use some system like the conversion rules for prenex normal form to syntactically manipulate a $\Sigma_n$ formula to check if it's equivalent to a $\Pi_n$ formula? This seems to avoid the provability formulation

Comment: About my past comment, I was not aware of formulae like "$R$ is a well-founded relation on a set" whose straightforward formalization is $\Pi_1$, but which admits an alternative $\Sigma_1$ formalization "there exists an isomorphism from $(Fld(R),R)$ to some ordinal". The fact that the latter is equivalent to well-foundedness cannot be proved in some weak set theories.

Comment: Also, all theorems of ZFC are $\Delta_0^{\textrm{ZFC}}$: ZFC proves they are equivalent to some tautology. (Friedman mentions this trick in *Boolean Relation Theory* when finding the complexity of Hilbert's 23 problems, except he used the analytical hierarchy in place of Levy's and 0=0 as the tautology.)